# iOS save combined image

Tags: ios, swift

I´ve created an draw module, where i am able to draw over an background image. The "drawings" are an transparent PNG, and i combine it when ill save the image.

But the problem here is that the contrast is sometimes bad to see (see image below).

Before (on paint mode):

[image]

After (when ill multiply both images):

[image]

(hard to see any yellow).

I multiply both images with:

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
  bottomImage!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: size.width, height: size.height))
  topImage!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: size.width, height: size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.multiply , alpha: 1.0)
  combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Any ideas how can i get better colors?

Comment: Why did you use `.multiply`? That seems pretty silly.

Comment: I would like to combine the content of both images. What else should ill use?

Comment: Well, there's [documentation available for CGBlendMode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgblendmode). If you just want to combine them, `.normal` seems like an obvious choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut the part about the blend mode. Just draw the "painting" (`topImage`)  directly onto the background (`bottomImage`).

Comment: Ah that was easy - ill guess ill used multiply when i was drawing with an "white" background (and not a clear PNG as top image) - and  then i need multiply (of course) - thanks for your answer!